# Connection refused on local server from outside connection

Tags: sockets, tcp

Im using the following code on my laptop as a server:

```
WSADATA wsd = { 0 };
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsd);

SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
SOCKADDR_IN sin = { 0 };
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(15000);
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");

bind(s, (const sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));
listen(s, 10);

int len = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);
SOCKET a = accept(s, (sockaddr*)&sin, &len);
```

And on my mobile phone the following code runs:

```
    Socket s = new Socket();
    try {
        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("*.*.*.*", 15000));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I used the same with telnet on another computer in my network with my public IP. Sadly i get the following exception message:

```
failed to connect to /*.*.*.* (port 15000): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Well, i rechecked my settings in the router, ipconfig gave me 192.168.1.109 as my laptops IP, as you can see in the following picture the port is forwarded to that IP:
[image: Port forwarding]

After i made sure once more that my firewall is deactivated ive fired up wireshark and checked port 15000. There is nothing incoming, no tcp packet. So obviously the packets are not coming to my computer and are refused earlier (router?)

I had it working a few days ago (two weeks tops) on another port where i hosted a server for our game we are working on. Same problem now, doesnt work anymore.

What could be causing the refusal of all incoming connections?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the image port 15000 is forwarded to my internal IP

Comment: I'd use `sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;` although I suspect that's not the problem.

Comment: Yea, right, i thought it was different in C++ :D. I should have written that i wrote the client and server in C++/.NET/Java to make sure its not an issue with the programming language.

Comment: And i just checked another setting in my router. It has an option to forward any unsolicited traffic to a station. I set it to my laptop, still nothing arriving

Comment: You need to telnet to `192.168.1.109`, not to `*.*.*.*`. You should not even be using `*.*.*.*` in your mobile code, either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem but i have no idea what actually is the cause. I deleted all forwarding services from the router and re-created them from scratch, now it works.

So if anyone else comes to this thread with a similar problem: If you have a Swisscom router remove all custom forwarding servers and recreate them, maybe it solves the problem.